# Find the arc length of $y=\sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

I am trying to find the arc length of $y=\sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$ over $\{0\leq x\leq 2\pi\}$ in terms of a and b. With the formula for the arc length I am unable to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \sqrt{1+\bigg( a\cos(ax) -b\sin\big(bx)  \bigg) ^{2} } dx $$
I have attempted to use numerous orthodox methods and they have all failed. I suspect it to be some non elementary result in terms of a and b. Any help solving this integral will be much appreciated.

Comment: This can probably be written in terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: Do you know the arc length of sinx? If yes, then then the arc length of this function can be calculated intuitively without any integration.

Comment: @K.defaoite. I have a very serious doubt about it

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda: I am afraid you didn't look carefully.

Comment: Are $a,b$ integers ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Try $a=1$ and $b=2$. No way (at leats for me). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: if $a,b$ aren't integers, the question does not even seem to make sense as the period is not $2\pi$. Indeed, for $1,2$ Alpha throws the glove.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yea... only if the period is still 2pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be totally wrong but I think that is $b\neq a$, there no solution to the antiderivative and the integral.

If $b=a$, we have
$$I=\int\sqrt{1+\Big( a\cos(ax) -a\sin(ax)  \Big) ^{2} } \,dx=\int \sqrt{1+a^2-a^2 \sin (2 a x)}\,dx$$
$$I=-\frac 1a E\left( \frac{\pi }{4}- a x|-2 a^2\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\Big( a\cos(ax) -a\sin(ax)  \Big) ^{2} } \,dx$$
$$J=\frac 1a \left(E\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|-2 a^2\right)-E\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-2 a \pi |-2 a^2\right) \right)$$

Comment: How would you solve the integral to get a non-elementary answer?

Comment: I am more than skeptical about a solution.